# Searching the values by using dynamic finders for two fields in grails

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am trying to search using dynamic finders for two fields: `status` and `OpenOn` (a date).

```
render(view:'list', model:[incidentInstanceList:Incident.findAllByStatusIlikeAndOpenOnGreaterThan("closed",new Date()-7,[sort:"id",order:"desc"])])
```

The above query searches the last 7 days, but I want to search for "last week", not the last 7 days. How can I do this?

Comment: Before I answer, just to be sure. Do you mean calendar aware "last week", like mon-sun in the last week, or just "today-14 days and a week from there"?

Comment: sir i want to search list for  lastweek mon-sun........

Comment: but it showing this error No signature of method: app.Incident.findAllByStatusAndCreatedOn() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [closed, [Mon Aug 01 15:07:04 IST 2011, Wed Aug 31 15:07:04 IST 2011]] Possible solutions: findAllByStatusAndCreatedOn(java.util.List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
def lastWeek
use(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory) {
    lastWeek = new Date() - 1.week
}

render(view:'list', model: [incidentInstanceList: Incident.findAllByStatusIlikeAndOpenOnGreaterThan( "closed", lastWeek, [sort:"id", order: "desc"])] )
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import java.util.Calendar
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def roundToLastMonday(date) {
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + Calendar.MONDAY)
    cal.getTime()
}

def getLastWeekRange() {
    def startDate, endDate
    use(TimeCategory) {
      startDate = roundToLastMonday(1.week.ago)
      endDate = startDate + 1.week - 1.second
    }
    [startDate, endDate]
}

def range = getLastWeekRange()
def result = Incident.withCriteria {
    like ("status", "closed")
    between ("open", range[0], range[1])
}
render(view:'list', model: [incidentInstanceList: result]
```

Comment: Its searching previous day data.but now i wants to search last week (mon to sun)  data.

Comment: Use `groovy.time.TimeCategory`, not `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory`.  The latter has been deprecated in favor of the former.